# How to Order Runscope test steps using Terraform

Tags: api, terraform, monitoring, blazemeter, runscope

When creating a Runscope testing using the [Runscope provider for Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/runscope/index.html), each test is created as a separate resource that references the test resource.

```
resource "runscope_test" "api" {
  name         = "api-test"
  description  = "checks the api is up and running"
  bucket_id    = "${runscope_bucket.main}"
}

resource "runscope_step" "step_1" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_bucket.bucket.id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"

  ...

}

resource "runscope_step" "step_2" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_bucket.bucket.id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"

  ...

}
```

[According to Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/load.html), the sequence in which resources are declared does not make any difference.

How does the Runscope provider for Terraform determine step sequence for the tests?

---

UPDATE

Looking at [implicit dependencies between resources in the Terraform documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies#implicit-and-explicit-dependencies), I found that I could simply reference the previous step.

> Terraform is able to infer a dependency, and knows it must create the
>   instance first.

In this case I used the `note` attribute of the second step to refer to the first step:

```
resource "runscope_step" "step_2" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_bucket.bucket.id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"
  note           = "Follows step: ${runscope_step.step_1.id}"

  ...
}
```

Comment: use `depend_on`?

Comment: @BMW, adding the ID of the previous step in `depends_on` gives me the following error: `depends on value cannot contain interpolations: ${runscope_step.step_1.id}`.

Comment: yes, the error is correct. The way you reference is wrong.  Change to `[runscope_step.step_1]` . Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies

Comment: I thought that syntax was for 0.12 and later, I'm still on 0.11

Comment: for this part, they are same usage in 0.11 and  0.12

Comment: I've tried that syntax and other variations, but I've not had any luck getting it to work. I'm sure it's user error on my part.  I got around it by using implicit dependency, which I outlined in the `UPDATE` section in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use implicit dependencies between steps like this:

```
resource "runscope_step" "step_1" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_bucket.bucket.id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"

  ...

}

resource "runscope_step" "step_2" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_step.step_1.bucket_id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"

  ...

}

resource "runscope_step" "step_3" {
  bucket_id      = "${runscope_step.step_2.bucket_id}"
  test_id        = "${runscope_test.test.id}"
  step_type      = "request"

  ...

}

and you can check dependencies via [terraform graph][1] command


  [1]: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html
```